# How to implement dns-sd in ktor

Tags: netty, ktor, dns-sd

I want to advertise the offered services to the local network.
Is there a nice way to integrate dns-sd or zeroconf/bonjour?

Answer (score 0):

I integrated a zeroconf implementation into the application

https://github.com/faceless2/cu-zeroconf

which is started and stopped due the ktor lifecycle. (ApplicationStarted / ApplicationStopped)

https://ktor.io/servers/lifecycle.html